# Changing Windows installation drive letter

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

Do I face any type of consequences by changing my Windows installation drive letter from C to something else? I ask because I have Windows on an SSD and some (stupid) programs automatically install to C. I don't want my SSD getting bloated, so I'd prefer that my HDD be the C drive and my SSD (with Windows on it) be the D drive. Will this create any problems?

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is, change the program folder location while installing it.  Programs ask where the files to be stored during setup. And for store apps open Settings > System > Storage and change new apps will save to from C to D.

Comment: Don't bother, SSDs can be written for ridiculous amount of times before failing.

Answer (score 0):

The tools check for system drive and will detect the changed driver and also put the data here. Modern SSDs can be written very often so that you don't have to care to minimize the amount of written data.